# Not sure how to debug this error in Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have tried to establish a connection to my MongoDB database "test".

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://new-user_31:blETQNNgi8IhG4pW@cluster0.70vfl.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["test"]
collection = db["test"]

post = {"_id": 0, "name": "tim", "score": 5}

collection.insert_one(post)
```

For some reason the query is not getting updated in the MongoDB database. The error its returning is the following -
[image]

Do you know how to fix the error?

Comment: Did you disclose your credentials in the question? Please don't provide screenshots, provide error message as text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: I think you have SSL certificate handshake issue. Also, don't share your credentials publicly.